# Molecular accelerators

Tags: electromagnetism, acceleration, molecules, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I wanted to know if we have accelerators for molecules just like particle accelerators. If so, what are they called and what is the maximum size of the molecules that can be accelerated in such accelerators? And what are the typical uses of such molecule accelerators?

Comment: Any charged entity can be accelerated. Buckyballs we’re done back in the 80’s. Not sure about bigger things more recently. Classic is Milliken and oil drops.

Comment: True. My question is are there any specific devices for accelerating molecules. When I try to search, all I get is particle accelerators. Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: Any electrostatic accelerator can do it. Van de Graaffs, Cockcroft-Waltons, if you can ionize it you can accelerate it (may have to upgrade lenses and mass selection magnets, but…).

Comment: Thank you. Will do more research on these.

Comment: Not sure if it is what you are asking for, or it can interest yiu, but I would mention mass spectroscopy

Comment: Particularly Time Of Flight mass spectrometers

Comment: Time of flight mass spectrometers looks interesting, thank you.. I guess to accelerate molecules, without charging it is difficult I guess.